# I am getting the following error using Next js. I am building an authentication pipeline using axios as the http client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

The error:
Server Error
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGOUT } from "../actions/types";

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initialState = user
  ? { isLoggedIn: true, user }
  : { isLoggedIn: false, user: null };

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        user: payload.user,
      };
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        user: null,
      };
    case LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        user: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to server side rendering and client side rendering. As Next.js provides SSR, you need to consider using objects like window, localStorage and so on. While compiling client side, those objects are fine but when Nextjs compiles server side, it shows error like you shared.

You can use something like this:

```js
let user = null;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
} else {
  // ... server-side logic
}
```

For other solutions see here: https://dev.to/vvo/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-errors-in-react-and-next-js-5f97

Comment: Hey thank you for your feedback. I have implemented what you have shared but the user still persists to be null.

Comment: It's not obvious if you code ever runs in browser. If it's not then you will never get the user data from the localStorage. In this case you should have the user data on the server side somehow.